# Jquery close toggle when other toggle is open

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have two sliding panels, panel1 is sliding down, while panel2 is sliding from left. I want to close panel1 when opening panel2. I know there's many similar question already been answered but I couldn't figure it out how do I apply those in my site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slide-btn1").click(function(){
    $("#panel1").toggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
  });
  $(".slide-btn2").click(function(){
    $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Edit: this is what I have done so far http://jsfiddle.net/Pukau/9CFgR/2/

Comment: Is this the effect you're after? http://jsbin.com/ixuyoj/2/edit

Comment: thanks for the answer! for some reasons it won't works but it gave me some clue how to apply it. that's really helpful. how can I rate you?

Comment: I am trying to understand what effect you want so I can provide an answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm currently on the train, I will post my complete code in jsfiddle soon when I reached home.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I added jsfiddle link. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slide-btn1").click(function(){
           $("#panel2").slideUp("fast");
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $("#panel1").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
        $(".slide-btn2").click(function(){
             $("#panel1").slideUp("fast");
           $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});​
```

for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/HT9Bx/