# Hide divs when showing another - jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I'll start with my JSFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/CR5FB/5/

Basically I'm trying to get the same effect as shown on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612004/jquery-close-toggle-when-other-toggle-is-open) ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/HT9Bx/)), however I'm having some trouble implementing it - being as I want to check for multiple div's toggle status rather than simply switching in between two divs. I have tried using the following:

```
$("#showcreate").click(function() {
if ($(".searchmenu").is(":visible")) {
    $(".createmenu").toggle("fast");
    $(".searchmenu").toggle("fast");     
} else {
    $(".createmenu").toggle("fast");
});
```

(So if the search menu is open, close it and open the create menu but if it's not open, just open the create menu).

I'm not sure if the `:visible` function applies if I've used `$("div").hide()` rather than display:none in the css?

Any help on this will be massively appreciated - even a suggestion for another suitable method such as possible jquery accordion etc.?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="actionsmenu" id="actionsmenu">
    <div id="navmenu">
        <ul id="navmenu">
            <li><a href='#' class="tog" data-id="createmenu" id='showcreate'>Create</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' class="tog" data-id="searchmenu" id='showsearch'>Search</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' class="tog" data-id="settingsmenu"  id='showsettings'>Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' class="tog" data-id="helpmenu" id='showhelp'>Help</a></li>
        <ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu createmenu" id="createmenu">Menu 1</div>
<div class="menu searchmenu" id="searchmenu">Menu 2</div>
<div class="menu settingsmenu" id="settingsmenu">Menu 3</div>
<div class="menu helpmenu" id="helpmenu">
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".menu").hide();

    $(".tog").click(function () {    
        $(".menu").hide();
        $("." + $(this).data('id')).toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/CR5FB/14/

**EDIT:**

You have to use some common class for your links and divs if you want to assign them to the same event.

**There is you can find better solution as for me: http://jsfiddle.net/CR5FB/19/**

Comment: I have a class in my CSS with the following code:

`
#navmenu li.active {
 background: #000000;
} 
`

would it be possible to activate this code so that when a list item is clicked, the css would 'show' using `addClass()` (i.e. when the subdiv is visible)?

Thanks again melvas!

Comment: Also tried `$("." + $(this).data('id')).toggle("fast").addClass('active');` within the if statement :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7nGYE/

What you need to do is keep track of the active menu with a CSS class, so when another menu is clicked, you toggle the active menu, remove it as active, then set the new menu as the active div.

In particular, on any menu item click:

```
$('ul#navmenu a').click(function() {
    $('div.active').removeClass('active').toggle('fast');
});
```

Hide the active menu. Then, on a particular menu item click:

```
$("#showcreate").click(function () {
    $(".createmenu").toggle("fast").addClass('active');
});
```

add the 'active' CSS class to keep track of it.

Comment: CSS solution is not bad, but improve your script, please: there is to many similar functions which make the same action